# Is it allowed to add a zero to a null pointer?

Tags: c++, null, pointer-arithmetic

I know that pointer arithmetic is disallowed for null pointers. But imagine I have something like this:

```
class MyArray {
  int *arrayBegin;  // pointer to the first array item, NULL for an empty array
  unsigned arraySize;   // size of the array, zero for an empty array
public:
  int *begin() const { return arrayBegin; }
  int *end() const { return arrayBegin + arraySize; }  // possible? (arrayBegin may be null)
```

Is it possible (allowed) to have the above `end()` implementation? Or is it necessary to have:

```
  int *end() const { return (arraySize == 0) ? nullptr : (arrayBegin + arraySize); }
```

to avoid pointer arithmetic with nullptr because `arrayBegin` is null for an empty array (despite `arraySize` also being zero in this case)?

I know it's possible to store `int *end;` instead of `unsigned size;` and let size be computed as `end-begin` - but then comes the same issue: Is it allowed to compute `nullptr - nullptr`?

I would especially appreciate standard references.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can add zero to the null pointer and subtract one null pointer from another. Quoting Additive operators [[expr.add]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add) section of the C++ standard:

> When an expression `J` that has integral type is added to or subtracted from an expression `P` of pointer type, the result has the type of `P`.
>
> - If `P` evaluates to a null pointer value and `J` evaluates to 0, the result is a null pointer value.

Comment: What is "8.7 7"? If you refer to the C++ Standard, please, specify which one. Generally, it is better to use section "names" in brackets, since section/chapter/paragraph numbering generally changes with each Standard version. In the current draft, the relevant section is [expr.add] paragraphs [4.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.1) and [5.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#5.1).