# Ensuring a char exists at the end of a struct

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, padding

In C, I want to place a `char` id at the *very end* of a struct so that I can discern the struct type from a pointer to the *end* of the struct (allocated dynamically). Obviously, the possibility of padding at the end makes this difficult. I thought of two approaches.

The first approach is to place an array of chars that extends all the way to the end of the struct so that `(char*)ptr_to_end - 1` always point to a valid char. I think this should work if the compiler is not doing any funny business. Otherwise, it should fail to compile:

```
typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
    char type;
} MyStructDummy;

typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
    char type[ sizeof( MyStructDummy ) - offsetof( MyStructDummy, type ) ];
} MyStruct;

_Static_assert(
    sizeof( MyStruct ) == sizeof( MyStructDummy ),
    "Could not ensure char at end of MyStruct"
);
```

The second approach is to use `offsetof` to *always* access the malloc-ed bloc as individual (member) variables and never as a complete struct. That way, we avoid ever imparting the struct's type as an effective type over the whole block or accidentally changing padding values:

```
typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
    char type;
} MyStruct;

int *MyStruct_foo( void *end_ptr )
{
    return (int*)( (char*)end_ptr - sizeof( MyStruct ) + offsetof( MyStruct, foo ) );
}

int *MyStruct_bar( void *end_ptr )
{
    return (int*)( (char*)end_ptr - sizeof( MyStruct ) + offsetof( MyStruct, bar ) );
}

char *MyStruct_type( void *end_ptr )
{
    return (char*)end_ptr - 1;
}
```

Is either of these approaches preferable to the other? Is there an existing C idiom that achieves what I want to achieve (I can't use a flexible array member because I want to maintain C++ compatability)?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Karl asked how placing an id at the end of a struct could be useful. Consider this memory-conserving implementation of a dynamic array/vector:

```
//VecHdr is for vectors without an automatic element destructor function
//and whose capacity is < UINT_MAX
typedef struct
{
    alignas( max_align_t )
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int cap;
    char type_and_flags; //At very end
} VecHdr; //Probable size: 16 bytes

//VecHdr is for vectors with an element destructor or whose capacity is >= UINT_MAX
typedef struct
{
    alignas( max_align_t )
    size_t size;
    size_t cap;
    void (*element_destructor_func)( void* );
    char type_and_flags; //At very end
} VecHdrEx; //Probable size: 32 bytes

//...

int *foo = vec_create( int );
//This macro returns a pointer to a malloced block of ints, preceded by a VecHdr

int *bar = vec_create_ex( int, my_element_destructor );
//This macro returns a pointer to malloced block of ints, preceded by a VecHdrEx

vec_push( foo, 12345 );
//vec_push knows that foo is preceded by a VecHdr by checking (char*)foo - 1
//foo's VecHdr may eventually be replaced with a VecHdrEx if we add enough elements

vec_push( bar, 12345 );
//vec_push knows that bar is preceded by a VecHdrEx by checking (char*)foo - 1
```

Comment: "*I want to place a `char` id at the very end of a struct*" - why? "*so that I can discern the struct type from a pointer to the end of the struct*" - why are you accessing the struct from the end and not from the front?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The idea is to implement dynamic containers by placing a header *before* the pointer suppied to the user. See the first paragraph [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70192823/placing-a-header-before-a-malloc-ed-block-pointer-arithmetic-and-undefined-beha).

Comment: @JDormer I think the memory usage should be the same in both approaches. Either that memory falls in the ```char``` array or is consumed by padding.

Comment: I still can't understand what *problem you are trying to solve* with this approach. Please show an example of code where you otherwise run into a problem due to not having the necessary information about a pointer, and justify why you could be in that situation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just updated the original question with a possible application.

Comment: I would place a constant-size main header block before the user-visible array, and another optional header block with additional data before the main header block. Its presence and size is determined by the type field in the main block.

Comment: offsetof seems sufficient. At that point it shouldn't matter where you put the char. You could also use an int (or two) to virtually guarantee alignment, although that's not guaranteed

Answer (score 1):

There will only be padding at the end if the last member is something misaligned, like a small integer type.

However, if you make the last member a flexible array member of character type, it will always be placed on top of such padding bytes, because the struct doesn't take a flexible array member in account when determining size and padding.

Example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
    char type[];
} MyStructDummy;

MyStructDummy* dummy = malloc (sizeof *dummy + 1);
printf("Size: %zu\n", sizeof(MyStructDummy));
printf("Address of struct:%p\n", dummy);
printf("Address of type:%p\n", dummy->type);
```

This is gives something like:

```
Size: 8
Address of struct:0x4072a0
Address of type:0x4072a8
```

If we add an extra member to ensure that there's padding at the end:

```
typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
    char causing_padding;
    char type[];
} MyStructDummy;
```

Then the very same code as above prints:

```
Size: 12
Address of struct:0x16f22a0
Address of type:0x16f22a9
```

So here the compiler did add padding but it lets us use byte 9 for data. We end up allocating memory beyond the flexible array member. Now, we could instead allocate the flexible array member to cover all of the padding:

```
size_t trailing_padding = sizeof(MyStructDummy) - offsetof(MyStructDummy, type);
MyStructDummy* dummy = malloc (sizeof *dummy + trailing_padding);
```

This still leaves `type` at address 9 but it now takes up 3 bytes. We could memset all of them with whatever code you wish to place there. This is well-defined and portable. Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
    char causing_padding;
    char type[];
} MyStructDummy;

int main (void)
{
  size_t trailing_padding = sizeof(MyStructDummy) - offsetof(MyStructDummy, type);
  MyStructDummy* dummy = malloc (sizeof *dummy + trailing_padding);
  memset(dummy->type, 42, trailing_padding); // write code 42 to all bytes
  
  printf("Size: %zu\n", sizeof(MyStructDummy));
  printf("Address of struct:%p\n", dummy);
  printf("Address of type:%p\n", dummy->type);

  unsigned char* endptr = (unsigned char*)dummy + sizeof(*dummy) - 1;
  printf("Value of last byte: %d", *endptr);
}
```

Output:

```
Size: 12
Address of struct:0xa842a0
Address of type:0xa842a9
Value of last byte: 42
```